# Function wont call inside a jquery .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to call a function inside a .click event. I know the .click is working because of console.log. Not sure why my function wont work. I have tried other solutions such as onClick() in the html with no luck.

Here are the links to be clicked on:

```
<h2 class="logo child"></h2>    
<ul>
    <li><a href="#web" class="nav-link">DEVELOPER</a></li>
    <li><a href="#design" class="nav-link">DESIGNER</a></li>
    <li><a href="#film" class="nav-link">FILM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function spinLogo()
    {
        $('.logo').css({
            'transition' : '1.5s ease-in-out',
            'transform' : 'rotate(360deg)'
        });
    }
setTimeout(function(){
    spinLogo();
}, 1000)

$('.nav-link').click(function()
    {
        spinLogo();
    });
});
```

I call the function when the page loads and it works without a problem.

**EDIT**

I added my logo to the code.

Comment: well for starters, you don't have a .logo in that html...

Comment: where's the html element with class = logo ?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to include a [mcve]. Without that, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You are declaring the function within the scope of another function, but calling it in the click handler as a global function.  Have you tried moving the spinLogo definition outside the ready handler?

Comment: The function is being called correctly. The problem is that setting `transform` to `rotate(360deg)` twice isn't going to make it spin twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the transition in the .logo class definition, and the transform in a separate class, and then just add that class name to the logo element when a .nav-link is clicked. You can remove the class after a timeout.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate the answer. It worked well.